# i get error when i import cv2 problem in vs code

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

my program worked perfect until i added
`import cv2`

[image]
without adding any instruction i get this errors

before i add import cv2 i added `import numpy as np` without error  i tried to `upgraid opencv` , numpy i get message that are updateed

Comment: Please post error as text not screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `opencv` package may be installed incorrectly. Use the following command to uninstall and reinstall it.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python
```

Or use the following command to update to the latest version.

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```

You can also create a new [virtual environmen](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_virtual-environments)t and reinstall the required packages.

Answer (score 0):

it work but not uninstall opencv but numpy!!
i use

`pip uninstall numpy pip install numpy`